# HTMLCanvasElement becomes HTMLUnknownElement in Iframe

Tags: html, iframe, canvas

I'm having trouble with my Canvas element...

I try to load a page with a Canvas element in an Iframe. when I try to alert the element-type like this:

```
var cv = document.getElementById("my_canvas");
alert("my_canvas = "+cv);
```

I get in every browser there is:

```
my_canvas = [object HTMLCanvasElement]
```

BUT, in Internet explorer I get:

```
my_canvas = [object HTMLUnknownElement]
```

so that is quite strange...

When I Load that samen page directly in my browser (not in the Iframe), it DOES give me the Canvas element.

Why is the element unknown in an Iframe???

And even more important: How do I FIX IT!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 and below do not support HTML5 Canvas.

It is quite possible, if using IE9, that the iframe is loading in a (IE7/8) compatibility mode.

Try adding this:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

To the top of your iFrame code. It is the correct doctype for HTML5 and will probably fix the problem.

Comment: You where right. It was a doctype problem. Not the iframe page doctype though, but the parent page doctype. In the iframe page I had allready added the doctype, because that is the actual page that uses HTML5. Apparently in Internet Explo(d/r)er the iframe doctype gets overruled by the inherited doctype...